# breeze.js and observable arrays, 2 copies of the data?

Tags: caching, breeze

I'm populating an observable array from a breeze.js API call (based on CodeCamper example from John Papa).  The observable is filled with this line of code, where "data" is the JSON load:

```
return _Observable(data.results);
```

After this completes, are there now 2 copies of the data, 1 in the entity manager cache, and also in this observable array in my vm?  Is there a way to tell breeze not to cache specific queries?  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the EntityQuery.noTracking method. Link:  http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/EntityQuery.html#method_noTracking

also a discussion here: http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/querying-depth

Comment: Thats exactly what I was looking for on the no tracking! I do have a question regarding my initial comment. From what I can tell, after I retrieve data, the entities are in the manager, they are in the obs array in my vm, and if bound to an updatable view component, the data is also displayed. So if I change a bound property in the UI, this first updates the obs array in the vm, and then the update is propagated to the entity in the manager, which causes its status to change. Is that the basic flow? Are there really 2 copies of the data or is the obs arr pointing to the entities in the EM?

Comment: With a normal query ( no noTracking) there is only one instance of the entity, not 2 copies, unless you copy it yourself.  However, i am not familiar with the _Observable function, i.e. whether this creates a reference to an existing entity or a clone. My guess is that it simply creates a wrapper, so you are still only dealing with one instance of each entity.

Comment: Let me echo that. There is only one entity instance - one "copy of the data". You have two *references* to that instance: a reference in the `EntityManager` and a reference in the "_Observable> `observableArray`.

Comment: thanks.  you guys have been very helpful.  I'm using breeze with a framework called Durandal and being new to all the components involved, it's hard to tell what is part of durandal, knockout, or breeze.  Even the coding practices of the author of the example I'm using as a guide comes into play.  There's a case where all the lookup tables are actually COPIED into a lookup object that's part of the datacontext.  I did a clear on the manager and my lookups still functioned, which had me confused.  But I see now that that's a special case.  btw, this is a great lib to work with.